How to instrument Cassandra db observability with springboot?
I'm trying to instrument cassandra java driver via springboot application . Can some one please suggest me out how we can configure for instrumenting cassandra driver in springboot ?
Can you please provide reference links or documents or some samples for the same ?

What do you mean by "trying to instrument"? It would be good if you provide additional context and background information on what you're trying to achieve to make it easier for others to help you. If you need guidance, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Cheers!

I'm trying to fetch all cassandra java driver metrices via micrometer and prometheus in a springboot application
